# Removing multi-value properties from RDF by Rowlex

Tags: .net, rowlex

I'm trying to remove properties with multi values, from RDF and it seems about this RDF, I should make below code for removing includeResource:

```
<Ontologyowl:StudyList rdf:about="stdl827181">
        <Ontologyowl:title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Basic learning materials</Ontologyowl:title>
        <Ontologyowl:includeResource>
            <Ontologyowl:LearningResource rdf:about="res298830"/>
        </Ontologyowl:includeResource>
        <Ontologyowl:includeResource>
            <Ontologyowl:LearningResource rdf:about="res323717"/>
        </Ontologyowl:includeResource>
    </Ontologyowl:StudyList>

StudyList_ stdl = (StudyList_)rdfDoc.GetIndividual(stdlId, StudyList.Uri, false);
LearningResource[] lrnRes = stdl.includeResources;

        foreach (LearningResource i in lrnRes)
        {
            stdl.RemoveincludeResource(i);
            rdfDoc.RemoveProperty(...);
        }
```

But I don't now about rdfDoc.RemoveProperty(..) inputs. Any help about this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rdfDoc.RemoveProperty(subject, predicate, object) actually requires you to specify the full triple. This method is wrapped by your stdl.RemoveincludeResource(i) method. However, your wrapping method is easier to read and is typesafe. The host C# object (stdl) is the subject, the method (RemoveincludeResource) represents the predicate, and the input parameter (i) will be the object. These items are passed on to the RdfDocument.RemoveProperty method internally. **There is no need to call both methods!**

Comment: I'm very thankful about your great helps and guides thourough this work